# Asp.Net Core WebAPI identity token login without email confirmation

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like users to login immediately after register the account i.e. without confirming the email and email has to be confirmed later any time.

Verification link for email confirmation is generated and sent.

When I try to login, it is getting failed. Looking into the solution I tried this:

```
services.Configure<SignInOptions>(options => {
                //options.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.RequireConfirmedAccount =false;
            });
```

But again, I am not able to get token without emailconfirmed field is set to true. Please help

Comment: Users do not have to confirm their email address for signin by default. Have you turned on this feature and can't turn it off? Or what's the problem?

Comment: @Mateech I've not code anything explicitly for this purpose. But I am sending confirmemail link.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `RequireConfirmedAccount` to **`true`** will not accept email for confirmation.

You can refer to the discussion in this [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13206), where the differences and connections between RequireConfirmedEmail and RequireConfirmedAccount are discussed.